# Specific and major difference between Simple TLV and BER TLV

Tags: iso

I want to know the specific difference between simple TLV and BER TLV

Why the BER TLV 5F05 05 48656C6C6F is Invalid as in BER TLV the tag can have one or more consecutive bytes???

Please give some examples also ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SIMLPE -TL:V vs BER-TLV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853800/simlpe-tlv-vs-ber-tlv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BER means bearer which allows the carriying of other TLV's within

BER-TLV data object contains (TL (TLV) (TLV) with a tag field followed by a length field encoding a number. 
The template, consists of one or more BER-TLV data objects, each one consisting of a tag field, a length field encoding a number and if the number is not zero, a value field.

In case its not clear feel free to contact me.

Regards
Anup

Comment: Thanks Anup for your answer.

I would like to add one more thing which is related to my question -

Why the BER TLV 5F05 05 48656C6C6F is Invalid as in BER TLV the tag can have one or more consecutive bytes???

Answer is - As in BER TLV the Tag field can be structured in following manner :

Comment: (ISO/IEC 7816 supports length fields of one, two, … up to five bytes)

1st byte       2nd byte       3rd byte       4th byte       5th byte 
"00" to "7F"     ---           ---            ----            ----
"81"           "00" to "FF"    ---            ----            ----
"82"             "0000" to "FFFF"             ----            ----
"83"                     "000000" to "FFFFFF"                 ----
"84"                           "0000000000"  to "FFFFFFFFFF"

Comment: So, in BER TLV 5F05 05 48656C6C6F -> The tag is of 2 bytes length (5F05) which is wrong because if the tag is of 2 bytes length then its first byte must be "81" and 2nd byte can be any in range "00" to "FF.

Feel free to ask in case of confusion.

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add one more thing which is related to my question -

Why the BER TLV 5F05 05 48656C6C6F is Invalid as in BER TLV the tag can have one or more consecutive bytes???

Answer is -

As in BER TLV the Tag field can be structured in following manner :
(ISO/IEC 7816 supports length fields of one, two, … up to five bytes)

In case when length of tag is 1 byte then the valid values can be -
"00" to "7F"

In case when length of tag is 2 bytes then the valid values can be -
"81" (for 1st byte) and "00" to "FF" (for 2nd byte)

In case when length of tag is 3 bytes then the valid values can be -
"82" (for 1st byte) and "0000" to "FFFF" (for 2nd + 3rd bytes)

In case when length of tag is 4 bytes then the valid values can be -
"83" (for 1st byte) and "000000" to "FFFFFF" (for 2nd + 3rd + 4th bytes)

In case when length of tag is 5 bytes then the valid values can be -
"84" (for 1st byte) and "00000000" to "FFFFFFFF" (for 2nd + 3rd + 4th + 5th bytes)

So, in BER TLV 5F05 05 48656C6C6F -> The tag is of 2 bytes length (5F05) which is wrong because if the tag is of 2 bytes length then its first byte must be "81" and 2nd byte can be any in range "00" to "FF.

Feel free to ask in case of confusion.

Comment: I know it's too late, but for future readers: please take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932655/1774251 that gives the correct explanation. Your tag 5F05 is correct based on the format (5 last bits of 5F are 1 so at least 1 more byte in T, first bit of 05 is 0 so this is the last byte of T). But it is incorrect based on BER-TLV interpretation as the second byte has a meaning and can't be less than 1F or the tag should have been written on 1 byte only.