# Building ICCDATA Parser using PHP

Tags: php, iso8583

Is there any ICCDATA Parser available in PHP ?
It should be ICCDATA data parser, I have ISO8583 parser, but that do NOT parses ICCDATA.

Comment: If google doesn't give you the answers you're looking for, then probably not.

Comment: @user723826 If my answer answered your question I would appreciate you up voting and accepting the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your answer is to properly [understand the element's format](http://chipnpin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/ber-tlv-encoding-of-emv-tags.html) and then searching for the correct thing.

I am assuming you are referring to Data Element 55 Integrated Circuit Data (ICC) when you say the ISO-8583 ICCDATA field. The EMV (ISO 7814), VISA, MasterCard, and other specifications are pretty clear on its format.

What you require is an [X.690 BER-TLV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690) parser to break down this portion of the message, not just a generic TLV field parser.

There have been some other posts on Stack Exchange as well on this, this is a good one. This is a good on on the differences between [simple and BER-TLV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853800/simlpe-tlv-vs-ber-tlv).

GitHub has BER-TLV parsers if you need a jump start and [this one by NuclearDog](https://github.com/NuclearDog/PHP-ASN.1/blob/master/parser.php) was one that came up towards the top of the list when searched.

Once you have your code written EMVLabs has a tool for helping you check you encoding or to see if you get the same result with their [BER-TLV decoder tool](http://www.emvlab.org/tlvutils/). *(obviously don't put production data there).*